# How do I run a shell script thorugh a cpp program?

Tags: c++, shell

I just wanted to know if i could make a c++ program make the shell script run. I have a shell script called ip.sh and i want to make a c++ program that runs it. So when I run the c++ program the script would run. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given the terminology you used in your question, you must be using Linux. Execute `man system` from the shell prompt, and read the shown documentation.

Comment: one more question. How would i do this in windows? would it be the same thing.

Comment: Use one of the `exec` family functions. I'd stay away from `system`. On Windows, use `CreateProcessEx`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `system()` function, from `<stdlib.h>`:

```
system("myfile.sh");
```

Reference: [`system` - cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/).

Comment: Given that this is C++, it's arguably better practice to include `<cstdlib>` and call `std::system()`.  It might also be worth noting the limitations of this library function (i.e. it's a *shell command string* that will be parsed).